# Network icon disappeared, no more internet

Tags: network-manager, 11.10

So, everything was working absolutely fine since Alpha 2 for me. Now yesterday only, I closed the lid of my laptop and I believe it did a so-called "bad shutdown". When I started it again this morning, the network icon wasn't in the top panel anymore and I can't connect to the internet (obviously). Google Chrome seems to be enable to start up too.

I tried a few things suggested here but none worked...

EDIT: This worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libnss3:i386 libnss3
```